# JSON Data Multiple Dropdown Menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, drop-down-menu, submenu

I try to create hover multiple drop-down context menu configurable for JSON.

```js
$(function () {

   var data = {
  menu: [{
   name: 'Ukraine',
   link: '0',
   sub: null
  }, {
   name: 'Croatia',
   link: '1',
   sub: null
  }, {
   name: 'Denmark',
   link: '2',
   sub: null
  }, {
   name: 'Canada',
   link: '3',
   sub: null
  }, {
   name: 'Columbia',
   link: '4',
   sub: null
  }, {
   name: 'Japan',
   link: '5',
   sub: null
  }, {
   name: 'Wales',
   link: '6',
   sub: null
  }, {
   name: 'England',
   link: '7',
   sub: [{
    name: 'Arsenal',
    link: '0-0',
    sub: null
   }, {
    name: 'Liverpool',
    link: '0-1',
    sub: null
   }, {
    name: 'Manchester United',
    link: '0-2',
    sub: null
   }]
  }, {
   name: 'Spain',
   link: '8',
   sub: [{
    name: 'Barcelona',
    link: '2-0',
    sub: null
   }, {
    name: 'Real Madrid',
    link: '2-1',
    sub: null
   }]
  }, {
   name: 'Germany',
   link: '9',
   sub: [{
    name: 'Bayern Munich',
    link: '3-1',
    sub: null
   }, {
    name: 'Borrusia Dortmund',
    link: '3-2',
    sub: null
   }]
  }]
    };
    var getMenuItem = function (itemData) {
        var item = $("<li>")
            .append(
        $("<a>", {
            href: '#' + itemData.link,
            html: itemData.name
        }));
        if (itemData.sub) {
            var subList = $("<ul>");
            $.each(itemData.sub, function () {
                subList.append(getMenuItem(this));
            });
            item.append(subList);
        }
        return item;
    };
    
    var $menu = $("#menu");
    $.each(data.menu, function () {
        $menu.append(
            getMenuItem(this)
        );
    });
    $menu.menu();
});
```

```html
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">

<style>

.ui-widget-content{padding-left: 20px;}

.ui-menu {
    width: 150px;
    height: 250px;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    direction: rtl;
    padding-left: 20px;
}
.ui-menu {
  overflow-y: hidden;
}
.ui-menu:hover {
   overflow-y: scroll;
}

.ui-menu .ui-menu-item{
 
     float: left;
    display: block;
}

.ui-widget .ui-widget{
 position: fixed;
 overflow: hidden;
 direction: ltr;
 padding-left: 0;
}
.ui-menu .ui-menu{
  position: fixed;
}


::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 13px;
}
body{
    overflow-y:hidden;
    padding-right:12px;
}
body:hover{
    overflow-y:scroll;
    padding-right:0px;
}
/* Track */
::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
    background: gray;  
}

/* Handle */
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    background: gray;  
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-button {
    background: #3C3838;
   
}
  </style>
</head>
<body>
 <ul id="menu" ></ul>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    
</body>
```

How to improve this code better for menu items: 
* If I click another place except menu it should close.
* If menu does not fit into the screen custom scroll should appear (something like this: [long list menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RUuPk.png))

Scrolling should happen when the user clicks up/down arrow.  The menu must scroll by 1 item up/down.  I have tried other options but it's not working.  Is it better to create it with pure JavaScript?

Answer (score 0):

You could add a span on the page that will show/hide the menu

```
  $('#showmenu').on(' mouseover', function() {
    $menu.show().focus();
  });
  $menu.on('mouseleave',function(){
    $(this).hide();
  });
```

See this in action here: https://jsfiddle.net/MarkSchultheiss/sm3wpmLa/